# Loop through specific name combination in a nested for loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, matrix, element, interaction

I am working with an interaction matrix (mat_SES) in R where rows are mammal species and columns are plant species. Each element is the Standardized Effect Size (SES) showing the departure from random association between a mammal and a plant species.
I want to make an object with SES values for specific combinations of species, that i have in another object (Mammal_plant_list). I am trying to do this with a nested for loop. Like this:

```
ses <- data.frame()
for (i in Mammal_plant_list$MAMMAL){
      for (j in Mammal_plant_list$PLANT){
 mat_SES[i,j] -> ses[i,j]
    }}
```

The mat_SES looks like this, where rows are mammal species and colums are plant species:

```
+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+
|                   | Abarema_adenophora | Abarema_auriculate | Abarema_barbouriana |
+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+
| Abrothrix_andinus |       -1.760111139 |        -1.13808418 |         -1.41032139 |
| Abrothrix_jelskii |        -2.01015237 |        -1.33864697 |         -1.65545444 |
| Akodon_aerosus    |         0.85578570 |         1.46373125 |          1.12302317 |
+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+
```

The Mammal_plant_list looks like this, where each row is the *i* mammal and *j* plant species I want to find the SES value for in the df_SES:

```
+---------------------+--------------------------+
|       MAMMAL        |          PLANT           |
+---------------------+--------------------------+
| Sciurus_granatensis | Astrocaryum_standleyanum |
| Sciurus_granatensis | Dipteryx_panamensis      |
| Sciurus_granatensis | Gnetum_leyboldii         |
| Sciurus_granatensis | Scheelea_zonensis        |
| Sciurus_granatensis | Gustavia_superba         |
+---------------------+--------------------------+
```

I would also like to include in the code, that it only should find the SES values that are larger than 2

The loop i am trying to make doesn't work for. It finds the right SES value for the first species combination, but then it stops. I get the error:

Subscripts out of bounds

Hope anoyone can help!